# Jules Verne's book about media

Tags: literature

Since [literature](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature) board is closed, the best board to ask this question might be here.
When I was very little, I remember seeing a review in TV. It was supposed to be a review on movie transpired by book by Jules Verne.

The main idea of the book was Vernes belief/imagination, that in the future, media will be the most powerful influence of politics and economy.

I remember seeing a scene where manager of big media company accepted and refused people asking him to help him just by making reportage about them.

Given to time Verne has lived, I'm really curious about the book. The way he imagined things he didn't know back then was always amazing.

So what's the name of the book? Does it even exist?

It might also be, that such a book doesn't simply exist and it's just a mess of multiple things in my brain. Yes that might be, but I've taken all thing for a fact many years, until I started searching for it now.

Comment: A list of the works of Jules Verne are readily found on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book:Jules_Verne

Comment: Since I was not even sure if it's Vernes Book or not, I prefered to ask someone who knows well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to the story "In the Year 2889", written by Jules Verne's son [Michael Verne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Verne), but published under Jules Verne's name. It contains a character "Frances Bennett", who is an immensely powerful media mogul.

Comment: For a moment I thought you were referring to the song "In the year 2525, if man is still alive."